# How do I link back to desktop version from mobile site using detectmobilebrowsers.com?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm using the JS from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ to redirect a client's old site to their mobile version. My question is how do I give users the option of viewing the desktop (full) version of the site From the mobile version? I have the mobile version on it's own subdomain "m.domain.com".